# Silverlight - button does not change a color

Tags: silverlight

I want to have the following behaviour - when user mouse over on button, text inside button change color. I create the following style + template:

```
<Style TargetType="blib:ButtonWithImage">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/buttonBackground.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="173"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="blib:ButtonWithImage">
                <Border x:Name="Background" CornerRadius="0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"></ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#D8FFFFFF"></ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".55"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,3,10,3">
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Text" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#FFFFF6BB" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` property should be attached to the root element in the Template which in this case is `Border` with the name "Background".  Currently you have it on the `Grid` inside the border but the `VisualStateManager` won't find it.

Also your `ButtonWithImage` class must be derived from `Button` (unless you have your own code to call GoToState) but I suspect you have that already.